# upgrading window 8.1 to windows 10 on a dual boot system will not boot windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Here is the situation. I have a Toshiba laptop running Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint 21.2 Mate. Been working for years.

Window 8.1 is coming to end of life and I need to upgrade to Windows 10, to support Photoshop - Lightroom (which are not supported under Win 8.1 now), etc. and my TAX program otherwise I use Linux 99% of the time.

I want to upgrade Window using the in place upgrade tool that Window provides. It work up to the point I do the initial boot to Windows 10 then fails. I believe it is because of the dual boot system provided by Grub. I believe I have to remove the Grub boot system and reestablish the windows boot loader which the upgrade tool I believe is looking for. I have found documentation on you site to remove Grub "Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader" and it makes sense.

What my question is: Once Windows is upgraded can I rebuilt the Grub boot system and thus avoid the Linux rebuild. I would like to do this so I preserve my /home partition which has all my software configurations like backintime schedules, etc. If so how do I do this. If I can't do this,

Second Option: Can I reinstall Linux with the in place partitions and get the dual boot back, I would only re-format /boot and / root partitions and leave /home alone.

I have /home backed up with backintime and I will do a cp of it to my external EXT4 device as well, I have Timeshift backed up all files in root and home also.

I also have a Macrium image of my Windows system also.

Can you help or point me in the right direction. Thanks

Also I know it is not a Linux problem if you know where I can get info to resolve my Windows upgrade issue without doing the above I would be great-full.
Thanks again and Seasons Greetings to all.

Comment: Windows 8.1 should have asked you to convert to UEFI and GPT. Did you do that. If not, you will have to back up, format and let Windows 10 create its 3 partitions. I did that earlier and the Windows 10 update worked fine.

Comment: Inf fact, Windows 10 is past its prime as well.  Best thing, is to consider a Windows 11 Pro computer so this situation does not face you in another 2 years.

Comment: @John When reading your comment my gut feeling told me "no, it can't be so soon" but you're right. We're almost in 2023 and Windows 10 will be supported until 2025 so 2 years indeed.